# Rails 3.1 + Nested Form + Client Side Validations + Twitter Bootstrap (v. 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, nested-forms, client-side-validation

Having set up Client Side Validations (3.2.1) and Nested Form (0.3.1) according to the docs and wikis, everything is working great, except for one thing: existing nested fields are being incorrectly uniqueness-validated in edit mode, i.e. they are being seen as new records. Existing non-nested fields within the nested_form validate as expected. Absent of the validations, all nested fields save and update perfectly.

Here is my code:

**_form.html.erb**

```
   <%= nested_form_for(@package, :validate => true) do |f| %>
     <%= render 'common/error_messages', :target => @package %>
     <div class="clearfix">
        <%= f.label :id %>
        <div class="input"><%= f.text_field :id, :readonly => "readonly" %></div>
     </div>
    ....................

     <h3>Events</h3>

    <div class="clearfix">
        <%= f.fields_for :packvents %>
        <%= f.link_to_add image_tag("icons/plus_16.png"), :packvents %> Add Event
    </div>


    <div class="actions">
            <a><%= f.submit "Save package","class" => "btn primary",:id => "submitBtn" %>       </a>&nbsp&nbsp<a><%= link_to 'Cancel', :back,"class" => "btn"  %></a>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

**_packvent_fields.html.erb**

```
 <div id="event" class="clearfix" >
    <%= f.link_to_remove image_tag("icons/delete_16.png"),:class => "event-delete"%>
  <div class="event_input"><%= f.select :event_id, grouped_options_for_select(Pevent.for_select(current_user), selected_key = f.object.event_id, prompt = nil),{},{:validate => true, :class => 'new_event'} %></div>
 </div>
```

Dynamically adding new fields works fine via the Client Side Validation callbacks combined with the Nested Form wiki code:

**rails.validations.callbacks.js**

```
window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.element.fail = function(element, message, callback) {
  callback();
  if (element.data('valid') !== false) {
    $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
    element.parent().find('.message').hide().show('slide', {direction: "up", easing: "easeOutBounce"}, 500);
  }
}

window.ClientSideValidations.callbacks.element.pass = function(element, callback) {
  // Take note how we're passing the callback to the hide() 
  // method so it is run after the animation is complete.
  element.parent().find('.message').hide('slide', {direction: "up"}, 500, callback);

    $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);

}
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event) {
  $(event.target).find(':input').enableClientSideValidations();
})
});
```

Removing the callbacks entirely has no effect, as does removing all extra divs, classes, etc. Adding an "on create/save" condition to the base validation is unworkable - it needs to work as fields are added dynamically:

**packvent.rb**

> validates :event_id, :uniqueness => {:scope => :package_id}

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Even more strangely, the last set of fields in the group validates correctly, even if it's the only one. Something to do with the multiple sets....